# Куда задавать вопросы по администрированию?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы

Можно ли ли на Ru StackOverflow, или есть специализированный сайт, два раза искал в списке Stack Exchange но не нашёл Администрирование.

И как реагировать на вопросы по администрированию, иногда на Ru So спрашивают.

Comment: англоязычный вынесли в [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) либо [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), русскоязычные вполне допустимы в ruSO